# Can longterm anxiety (fear of disease-nosemaphobia) cause chronic gastritis

Tags: digestion, gastroenterology, hypochondria, proton-pump-inhibitors, nosemaphobia

I've had chronic gastritis (with a healed ulcer and 2 times erosive gastritis) for over 6 years now. I've also had 4 gastroscopy procedures. I can't find the cause of it up to this date.

From the causes which are listed on [Mayo clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/gastritis/basics/risk-factors/con-20021032)
I could not find myself in any of the possible listed causes. I've been tested negative for H. pylori for 4 times (2x biopsy, stool sample, blood sample), I don't take NSAID's, I don't drink alcohol, I don't smoke, I'm not old (24 years now), I don't have autoimmune gastritis, I don't have any other illness which could cause ch.gastritis, no-one ever in my family (both sides) never had any digestive issues neither have I been under immense stress. I've also been tested for celiac (biopsy and blood) and the results were negative.

The only thing that I have is that I'm worrying about diseases (hypochondriac) but I don't consider it to be an issue. I'm a social person and never had any panic attacks or any other social phobia.

For the last three years no matter what I  swallow I nearly always get some pain in my stomach. When I take PPI's or H2 blockers I feel fantastic but I want to abandon medications for good. Gastroenterologist keeps saying that this is due to my anxiety since there is no H. pylori but this just blows my mind...

Could it be something that they've missed (maybe H. pylori hiding somewhere even if 4 tests were done previously). Could it be some specific food ingredient which is causing such damage or anything else?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that strangers on the internet are going to think of possibilities your doctors haven't considered. A more productive approach if your doctors are stumped is finding new doctors to take a fresh look at it. Don't be shy about asking for second, third and fourth opinions.

Comment: @CareyGregory you are right Sir. I' ll definitely do that.

Comment: Sounds like you have typical case of health anxiety which is causing a mix of problems. I suffered, and still stuff from health anxiety, its the thought process and you constantly scanning your body for problems that are not actually there. The constant scanning your body for sensations, pains and combined with the worry actually stress on your body and creates tension in blood vessels and muscles, this actually creates pain. I went 6 years of my life believing my chest pain could kill me at any moment, the first 3 years they said it was GERD or Heart... test after test... nothing.

Comment: 6 years they tried to find a cause but couldn't, they finally diagnosed me with suspected nerve damage as they had ruled everything else out... even the best MRI in the world can't pickup low grade nerve damage. Once I accepted that the pain might be not life threatening, nor treatable, the pain actually got better &  manageable, sometimes I feel mild pain, other times not at all. Its normally very painful when I have stress, or have anxiety... Ask your doctor for Health Anxiety Counselling along with continuing to do tests on you.

Comment: Yep, health anxiety affected my body, my digestive system to be precise everything else is clear. I believe I'll conquer it though.

Answer (score -1):

This answer may be hard to swallow, but the knowledge has helped others, including my wife. You can be sensitive to gluten and still test negative for celiac disease.  There is a wealth of knowledge here to start your search.  http://www.beyondceliac.org/celiac-disease/non-celiac-gluten-sensitivity/ 
Be prepared to eliminate foods (even ones marked as "gluten free" in many cases).

The good news, if you are sensitive to glutens, you can still over come the symptoms but it will take a change in diet.